# Dynamically load and remove external js

Tags: jquery

I would like to load an external js file if a browser width exceeds 640px and remove the same js file if the browser width goes below 640px.

Here's what i've got so far:

```
function setSize() {
  var state = $(window).width() < 640;
  if (state != currentState) {
    currentState = state;
    if (state) {
      $.load( "js/test.js" );
    } else {
      $.remove( "js/test.js" );;
    }
  }
}

setSize();
$(window).on('resize', setSize);
```

I know the function works but i don't know how to load and remove the external js.

Thanks

UPDATE

```
var currentState = false;

function setSize() {
var state = $(window).width() < 640;
if (state != currentState) {
currentState = state;
if (state) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
$(".pagination li").eq(0).addClass("selected");
window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
    auto: 3000,
    continuous: true,
    // disableScroll: true,
    // stopPropagation: true,
    // callback: function(index, element) {},
    callback: function(index, element) {
        var $Elements = $(".pagination li").removeClass("selected");
        $Elements.eq(index).addClass("selected");
    },
    // transitionEnd: function(index, element) {}
});

var $navLi = $('#nav li');
$navLi.on ('click', function () {
    window.mySwipe.slide($(this).index(), 200);

    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$('#mySwipePrev').on('click', function () {
   mySwipe.prev();
   $navLi.removeClass('selected');
   $navLi.eq(mySwipe.getPos()).addClass('selected');
});
$('#mySwipeNext').on('click', function () {
   mySwipe.next();
   $navLi.removeClass('selected');
   $navLi.eq(mySwipe.getPos()).addClass('selected');
});   

} else {

}
  }
}

setSize();
$(window).on('resize', setSize);
```

Comment: I don't think you can just call remove, this method was made to remove dom elements - see http://api.jquery.com/remove/ I don't think there is any way to "remove" a script from a page as it is being loaded then executed. What you want to do is to write some logic to undo what test.js does.

Comment: You can't easily remove external JS, but you can conditionally include one OR the other.

Comment: @AlexanderKludt What i am trying to do it add a script if the browser goes below 640px, I can get this working but when I change the width beyond 640px then the script stays and I need to refresh. I'll update the post to show you my code

Comment: @MightyPork see above comment

Comment: So how about you make a function to do the changes and call it when needed, instead of loading a whole new file?

Comment: @MightyPork Here's a fiddle to help explain it more, http://jsfiddle.net/digitalk/ewaw3xjp/2/show When you make the browser below 640px the script works, when you make the browser bigger again it should return back to a grid. I think this is because the script is still loaded?

Comment: Just incase it's the red part

Answer (score 0):

You can place the loaded file in some html holder element like div or span

```
$("#someDivElement").load( "js/test.js" );
```

and to remove

```
$("#someDivElement").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot remove the js reference from a page. But you can add one as below

```
window.onload = function() {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.src = '_foo.js';
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

Thus you should not add a static reference to your page but add it dynamically based on your conditions.